The fundamental group of n dimensional sphere
In the book of Allan Hatcher in the proof of

Proposition 1.14: $\pi_{1}(S^{n}) = 0$ if $n \geq 2$

I don't understand why $A_{1}\cap A_{2}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$, where $p$ and $q$ denote the north and south pole of $S^n$, respectively, and $A_1 = S^n - \{p\}$ and $A_2 = S^n - \{q\}$.
How to prove it?

What are $A_1$ and $A_2$? Please edit into the post.

$A_1 \cap A_2$ is $S^n - {p,q}$, meaning the sphere with both poles removed. Intuitively, you can widen those holes until the whole punctured sphere becomes a cylinder.

...or identify the twice-punctured sphere with the once-punctured Cartesian space with $0$ removed, and use (generalized) polar coordinates $x \leftrightarrow(x/|x|, \log|x|)$.

Let's represent $S^n$ as the set of all $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ satisfying $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2 + x_{n+1}^2 = 1$. Then $S^n - \{p,q\}$ consists of the points in $S^n$ for which $x_{n+1} \neq \pm 1$. Since $x_{n+1}^2 < 1$, $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots x_n^2 > 0$.
Define $f \colon S^n - \{p,q\} \to S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
    f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}) = \left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots +x_n^2}},\dots, \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots +x_n^2}}, \frac{x_{n+1}}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2}}\right)
$$
Then
$$
    f^{-1}(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n,t) = \left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\dots,\frac{y_n}{\sqrt{1+t^2}},\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)
$$

Thank you so much for your help

First move the points $p$ and $q$ along $S^n$ so that they're antipodal which is possible since $S^n$ is path connected for $n \geq 1$. Each point on the interior of the line connecting $p$ and $q$ will have a copy of $S^{n-1}$ orthogonal to it. These would be the lines of latitude on $S^2$ that are parallel to the equator. So the space is then homeomorphic to the cylinder $S^{n-1} \times (0,1)$. But now we're done since $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you so much for your help
